# Build System.Data.SQLite with Enhanced Query Syntax

Tags: .net, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I need to build System.Data.SQLite with SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS enabled, to get the 'Enhanced Query Syntax' (http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_3_1)

I downloaded the source code [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.89.0/sqlite-netFx-source-1.0.89.0.zip):

[I have tried following the build guide:](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/build.wiki)

I am using the 2010 version because I need it in .net 4.0. I have opened the solution and rebuild it. I needed to unload the test projects first because they failed.

I have added the following in SQLite.Interop.2010.props 'SQLITE_COMMON_DEFINES' tag:

> SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS=1;SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS4=1;

And to make sure it was defined I changed it in sqlite3.c (Properly not needed):

```
//#ifdef SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3
  "ENABLE_FTS3",
//#endif
//#ifdef SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS
  "ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS",
//#endif
//#ifdef SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS4
  "ENABLE_FTS4",
//#endif
```

I rebuild it with release config, and it succeeded. But when I look in the folder:

> sqlite-netFx-source-1.0.89.0\bin\2010\Release\bin

I do not find the SQLite.Interop.dll.

How do I build it and get the SQLite.Interop.dll??

Comment: DO NOT change `sqlite3.c`! With these changes, you would get incorrect output from [PRAGMA compile_options](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_compile_options).

Comment: Well it should not make any difference, undoing it doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm - I found the problem.
I needed to build with ReleaseNativeOnly config, to get the SQLite.Interop.dll. The win32/x86 file is placed in sqlite-netFx-source-1.0.89.0\bin\2010\Win32\ReleaseNativeOnly.

To get the 64 bit version change platform for Interop project by select properties on the solution, and change platform to x64 - rebuild.
The file is placed in sqlite-netFx-source-1.0.89.0\bin\2010\x64\ReleaseNativeOnly.

I copied them to my project folder in the x86 and x64 folders and it works.